# Huge tables won't fit on mobile, can I tell Google the page is desktop only?

Tags: robots.txt, mobile, meta-tags

I'm working on a product comparison page that is composed of a giant table listing the attributes of a great many products. It's useful on a desktop for those who want to dig into the details of product specifications, but it's completely useless on a mobile device. I can't think of any way of showing a comprehensive table of all this info on a mobile and having it work at all.

It's easy to use media queries to hide the links to that page for users on mobile devices, but I'm concerned about search traffic.

I could exclude it in robots.txt but it might be nice to have that page indexed to pull in some desktop and tablet traffic.

Is there any kind of meta tag that can be used to tell Google to not display this page in the SERPs when the user is searching on a mobile?

Comment: I don't think its possible now without some type of cloak and dagger method. They used to list `Googlebot-Mobile` in their user agent but I think they now just use Googlebot, like the desktop because before you could use `User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile Disallow: /path/to/block`. You can test if they do or don't support it, by doing a fetch test within Google Web Console.

Comment: There are many examples of responsive tables designed to fit into mobile pages. Take a look at a few: https://codepen.io/collection/AdGVYP/#

Answer (score 1):

I use table saw. What happens with whatever responsive table framework you use is that only a few columns show instead of all.
Or the columns are stacked.